# NLP - support comments analysis

Tags: python, nlp, bert

I am new to NLP and looking for some direction since after all my reading I haven't found a definite approach and the subject matter is vast. The project is to focus on specific fields of support comments using NLP and Python. The goal is that from the comments I want to verify that the comment is in fact a well made comment for that field. Some requirements is the context of entered text is relevant to the field it has been entered in, it is informative based on the specific field, it is not just a few unhelpful words entered, it can detect that words/sentences have similar semantic meaning (e.g problem is, issue encountered etc).

I first looked into TF-IDF but it doesn't consider context. I have been reading into other deep learning models such as BERT as it includes context. I have read though that BERT was designed more for sentence prediction and missing words rather than for comparing semantic meaning of multiple sentences. USE would be better for comparing if sentences are similar although all the comments will have a general theme and I doubt they will be similar enough to design a system around. Topic modelling sounded like what i'm looking for but I think it's more for general topics you find in newspapers and books rather than comment sections. For the text summarisation option maybe there is not enough text in each comment to give a helpful summary. I think I would prefer unlabelled data if possible so as to minimise manual input but if it's neccessary then we could evaluate it. Is there something in fine tuning a pretrained model such as BERT to analyse all the existing comments for a specific field and somehow extract from that if a new comment is informative and relevant by comparing it to the existing ones?

Example field would be "Problem description". I am looking for direction on how to classify the content of that field as relevant and informative.

Any direction is appreciated or if you know of existing related material, papers, videos or tutorials.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Can you please add an example or two? Or at least define what you mean by a "well made" comment, this seems quite subjective. And what are the "fields", where do they come from? is is a fixed predefined set, an input to the system?

Comment: We have chosen a few fields, "Problem description" is one, "Current status" is another. The subjective nature of the comments and what makes them good is part of the problem to solve. People make comments differently. Use different words etc. Two different comments might both be good/informative updates for the purposes of what is inside the comments. What makes it good may be that the sentences are well formed, the comment isn't just a few words such as "working on it", that's what i'm trying to get my head around. There are existing comments to compare new comments to, if that helps.

Comment: Detecting grammatically well formed comments, or short comments which are unlikely to be useful, is relatively easy. But it looks like you are looking for something more precise than this, without having exactly defined what it is. I'd suggest that you start by taking a sample of random comments and annotate them, preferably by several annotators. This way you could clarify the task, because currently there's no way the system will magically guess what is the expected output. Additionally it looks like task is actually quite specific and therefore probably needs to be supervised, so ...

Comment: it's likely that you will need labelled data for training. Unsupervised can only give you standard tasks, for example topic modelling, sentiment analysis, grammatical correction.

Comment: Thanks Erwan I will look into what you have suggested. Do you think BERT is a suitable tool for this?

Comment: To me the task is under-specified so far. As long as the precise goal of the task is not clear, it's impossible to know if a method is suitable for it. Try to carefully define what you want the system to do, at least with some examples, otherwise it's unlikely that any approach will do what you want.